# Neo4j/Cypher | Not getting unique results from the database

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, unique

I'm trying to get completely unique results from my Neo4j database.

I have a database with all kinds of movies, users can *watch* movies, and movies can be *similar to* each other. I'm trying to get a completely unique list of movies that are related to the movies that the user already watched, and filter out the movies that are already watched.

As far as I know this should work by using `RETURN DISTINCT m`, but that doesn't work if you have watched multiple movies that are similar to one movie.

So to make it simple:
User watched movie `A`, `B` and `C`. All of those movies are similar to movie `D`
Right now, it returns: `D, D, D`.

I tried both `DISTINCT movie` and `collect(DISTINCT m)` without success

The complete query I'm using is:

```
MATCH (u:user {name:'" + user + "'})-[:watched]->()-[r:is_similar_to]-(m)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:watched]-(m) 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT m), r ORDER BY r.rated
```

I hope you guys can help me out,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the "non unique" movies is because you have returned "r".

There is an implicit group by r here. When you switch to the Rows view you can see that you will have 3 rows with unique relationships (r) and within the row unique movies.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
MATCH (u:user {name:'" + user + "'})-[:watched]->()-[r:is_similar_to]-(m)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:watched]-(m) 
RETURN m, sum(r.rated) as score
ORDER by score DESC
```

You will than have unique Movies and the sum of all the related scores.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works like a charm! Bedankt!